# When accessing a variable from an ISR, is a volatile pointer enough?

Tags: interrupt

Let's say I want to modify a global variable from inside an [interrupt](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/) service routine. I must ensure that any variables I modify are volatile. Does it work to use a volatile pointer to data I want to modify if the data itself is not volatile?

In my case the data is a struct, but does the answer change if the data is a class, array, or just a variable?

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>

#define PIN_INTERRUPT  2

typedef struct MyStruct
{
    int a_field;
} MyStruct;


MyStruct struct_data;
int array_data[32];

volatile bool _flag_ISR = false;
volatile MyStruct *_struct_ISR = &struct_data;
void myISR()
{
    // just some example stuff
    int read = digitalRead(PIN_INTERRUPT);
    _struct_ISR->a_field = read;
    _arr_data_ISR[4] = read;
    
    _flag_ISR = true;
}

void setup()
{
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(PIN_INTERRUPT), myISR, CHANGE);
}

void loop()
{
    if (_flag_ISR)
    {
        // do processing here...
        _flag_ISR = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question the first couple passes through, probably because (I'm guessing) by "volatile pointer" you really meant "pointer to volatile" and the distinction **is important**.  So, are you asking: "with respect to communicating between the ISR and the main line of execution, is it sufficient to use a pointer-TO-volatile *if* the thing being pointed-to is, itself, not volatile qualified?"

Answer (score 1):

First, beware that what you have written is not a volatile pointer, it's
a pointer to volatile data. If you always access the object through this
pointer, you should be fine. If you use the pointer in the ISR, but
access the data directly in the main code (bypassing the `volatile`
qualifier), then the program could fail.

Consider the following:

```cpp
void loop()
{
    if (_flag_ISR) {
        _flag_ISR = false;
        Serial.println(struct_data.a_field);
    }
}
```

Once the compiler inlines the call to `loop()` from `main()`, the
main program looks like

```cpp
int main()
{
    init();  // Arduino core initialization
    setup();
    for (;;) {  // inlined loop()
        if (_flag_ISR) {
            _flag_ISR = false;
            Serial.println(struct_data.a_field);
        }
    }
}
```

And now, since `struct_data` is not volatile, the compiler can
legitimately optimize the code by avoiding repeatedly accessing the same
RAM location:

```cpp
int main()
{
    init();  // Arduino core initialization
    setup();
    register int data_copy = struct_data.a_field;
    for (;;) {  // inlined loop()
        if (_flag_ISR) {
            _flag_ISR = false;
            Serial.println(data_copy);
        }
    }
}
```

And now the program prints only zeros.

Comment: Voting yours up.  I think I took their "volatile pointer" phrasing too literally.  Assuming they confirm this understanding of what they meant your answer has pretty much everything I'd have to say about it anyway.  I'm sort of surprised you're using the register keyword.

Comment: @timemage: The `register` keyword is seldom useful in actual code. Here I am using it only to express the idea that the compiler can choose to keep a copy of the data in an internal CPU register (or set of registers).

Comment: It's the latter half of that that I was looking for.  You know, you're not even allowed to use it in `17.